# Window Menu Bar Issue

Tags: compiz, metacity

I installed Ubuntu Natty (11.04) a while ago and also CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm) for better display effects.

This was working fine till now but since a few days ago due to some unknown reason

1) The minimize,maximize,close buttons get disappeared at start-up.
2) even the show desktop button when clicked shows "your window manager does not support the show desktop button, or you are not running a window manager" and the window switcher also doesnt work.

They were only restored when I ran the command "compiz --replace" or "metacity --replace" in the terminal everytime after the system booted up which not only restored all my windows back to normal as they were after I had installed Natty but also led to the terminal hanging up as if it was closed then it called for a reboot as I virtually couldnt access anything simultaneously.

Now I uninstalled CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm) as well as Unity and kept only the Metacity but I still face the problem which gets resolved only after I run "screen metacity --replace" on every reboot

Please help me with a solution that will restore my windows back to normal permanently and which doesnt involve typing or running anything everytime in the terminal after boot.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first a hint: if you want to run a process on a terminal in background (you described it as "terminal hanging") you should append an "&" to it:

metacity --replace &

I guess at bootup neither metacity nor compiz are running on your machine. It is difficult to say why this happened.

A suggestion would be to reinstall the desired manager (compiz or metacity).

greetings from switzerland, Michael

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,sir but it doesnt seem to solve the issue completely. Although,what you said is a good way to keep the terminal from hanging up but that can also be done by ***"screen metacity --replace"***. 
And your guess is absolutely right that neither compiz nor metacity are running at bootup..What I want is,how that can be done so as it will save me the trouble of running the terminal at bootup..

Comment: you can run your prefered manager as an autostart application (see Menu System -> Preferences -> Start Applications). The names might differ slightly as I do not have the english version setup.